# Paso de parámetros entre dos controladores angular 2

Tags: ionic, angular

En angularJS podía hacer uso de una variable rootscope compartida entre todos los controladores y vistas, necesito compartir una variable entre dos controladores en un proyecto de ionic con angular 2, y hasta ahora no he encontrado nada sobre como hacerlo.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: se pasan a traves de service o factory , las buenas practicas recomiendan services

Answer (score 2):

Si bien el uso de un servicio como singleton es una opción, la manera correcta es utilizar los decoradores @Input() @Output() para compartir parámetros entre objetos.

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo y fácil de entender:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Persona } from './persona';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  cliente: any = { nombre: 'Joaquín' };
  cambioPersona(persona: Persona) {
    this.cliente = persona;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    {{cliente | json}}!
  </h1>
  <app-hijo [clienteEnHijo]="cliente" (onClienteChange)="cambioPersona($event)"></app-hijo>
</div>
```

El selector 'app-hijo' pasa como parametro la variable "cliente" como un **@Input** y el evento "cambioPersona" como **@Output**

**hijo.component.ts**

```
import { Persona } from './../persona';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hijo',
  templateUrl: './hijo.component.html',
})
export class HijoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() clienteEnHijo:Persona;
  @Output() onClienteChange = new EventEmitter<Persona>();

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }

  cambiarCliente(){
    this.clienteEnHijo = {nombre:'Benito'};
    this.onClienteChange.emit(this.clienteEnHijo)
  }
}
```

**hijo.component.html**

```
<p>
  hijo works!{{clienteEnHijo|json}} 
</p>
<button (click)="cambiarCliente()">Cambiar cliente</button>
```

**persona.ts**

```
// Interfaz
export interface Persona {
    nombre: string,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Como bien te comentan, se utiliza un servicio, en angular 2 yo lo hago de esta manera ya que me permite manejar los mensajes de una forma prolija y eficiente.

Utilizo un servicio como este que se comunica con todos los componentes que necesito:

```
@Injectable()
export class Servicio{
  getValue: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});

  setValue(value){
    return this.getValue.next({valor: value});
  }

}
```

Para que se pueda entender mejor, te dejo un ejemplo en plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wl9Lda9hULSxMy2kJjvM?p=preview

Espero que sea lo que necesitas, en caso contrario, no dudes en volver a preguntar.

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba!! Funciona perfecto.

Comment: Excelente, saludos