# ¿ como pasar datos entre dos controladores Angular 8 usando @Input?

Tags: angular, estructuras-de-datos, component, input, parametros

Buenos dias / tardes:
He leido y visto el link [Paso de parámetros entre dos controladores angular 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78216/paso-de-par%C3%A1metros-entre-dos-controladores-angular-2/97966#97966) de paso parametros. Cuando yo hago....

```
       <app-form-pregunta   [AuxEnfermedad]="enfermedad"  ></app-form-pregunta>
```

Le paso los datos que recojo con @input. Pero si uso routingLink  :

```
  <label id="paginacion "> Selecciona una enfermedad y pulsa abajo el botón correspondiente </label>
    <mat-radio-group
    aria-labelledby="paginacion-enfermedades-group-label"
    class="paginacion-radio-group"
    [(ngModel)]="enfermedadSeleccionadaId"
    >
        <mat-radio-button class="paginacion-button" *ngFor="let enfermedad of Enfermedades" 
        [value]="enfermedad" >
            {{enfermedad.enfermedad}}
        </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>


<button id="miboton" routerLink  ="/PagePregunta"   (click) =  buscarPreguntas(enfermedadSeleccionadaId) >Buscar</button>
</div>
```

intento hacer lo mismo pero me dice que button no permite `[AuxEnfermedad]="enfermedad"`.  Donde y como he de pasar el objeto que quiero al otro componente. ¿ Donde pongo `[AuxEnfermedad]="enfermedad"`?

En este caso, tanto `/PagePregunta` como de donde viene `/PageEnfermedades` son mostrados con `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` mientras que `<app-form-pregunta >` no ya que es hijo y se muestra como anexo de la pagina que en ese momento esta en /router.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Veo que siempre puedo pasar parametros como parte de la URL, pero es tan comodo y facil usar `[AuxEnfermedad]="enfermedad"` y `@Input()` que me resisto a pensar que NO puedo usarlo así ahora. Gracias.

Comment: Hay una diferencia que no estás tomando en cuenta: `attr="value"` pasa por input el string "value", `[attr]="value"` pasa por input la variable "value". Usando square-brackets se envía código (variables, operaciones ternarias, etc). Sin los brackets, se mandan directamente literales (como en HTML).

Comment: tienes que entender `routerLink` es para navegar entre componentes que tienes definidos en el router. y los `@Inputs` son datos que puedes pasar a los componentes que has definido. No puedes pasar cualquier cosa a los componentes tienes que ver que `inputs` pueden recibir. No queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer la verdad

Comment: Al final he pasado los datos por medio de un servicio y un observable. Lo que quería hacer era: Estoy en la pagina con varias enfermedades. Selecciono una y se me abre otra página con las preguntas de ESA enfermedad seleccionada. Para ello, el componente necesita recibir la enfermedad o su id. Intentaba pasar de un componente a otro un dato. No pude con @input, tampoco con router params y al final lo hice como (https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/ )  dice ahí con servicio.

Answer (score 0):

la manera de usar @Input es la siguente:
Se entiende que cuando utilizas el decorador @Input es para pasar valores del componente padre al hijo.

Ejemplo:

```
variable_padre: string = "Querido hijo"
```

**padre.component.ts**

```
<app-hijo-component [recibir_de_padre]="variable_padre"></app-hijo-component>
```

**padre.component.html**

Este es el valor que le vamos a pasar a nuetro componente hijo.

El decorador @Input se declara en el componente hijo adonde vamos a recibir lo que el componete padre nos esta diciendo.

```
@Input() recibir_de_padre: string;
```

**hijo.component.ts**

Una ves se obtenga el mensaje del padre en el componente hijo podemos usar la valiable **recibir_de_padre**

Para añadir algo mas, seria bueno que te leyeras el [ciclo de vida de los componentes en angular](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), ya que algunas veces te ayudara bastante el ngOnChanges, si llegas a manejar estos decoradores mas a fondo.

Comment: Gracias, pero entre padres e hijo ya lo uso bien. Era saber si se puede usar entre hermanos o dos componentes que no tengan relación padre e hijo. Gracias por contestarme.

Comment: lo que buscas es servicios, básicamente creas un servicio que se vuelve estático para la aplicación y a este servicio le puedes agregar o buscar información desde cualquier componente, puedes hacer encapsulamiento para que solo esté en cierta sección de la aplicación también

Comment: Usa servicios, el servicio sería como el intermediario entre los componentes hermanos que no tienen relación