# ¿Cómo enviar datos entre controladores en Angular 8 usando Route Parameters?

Tags: angular8, component, input, parametros, angular-router

Buenos días/tardes,

Estoy bastante perdido y me encantaría si alguno puede ayudarme. Después de intentar usar @Input para intentar pasar parametros/datos entre controladores que `no`  son padre e hijo ( pude cuando lo son, pero estoy esperando que alguno me ilumine cuando NO lo son [¿ como pasar datos entre dos controladores Angular 8 usando @Input?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/345217/como-pasar-datos-entre-dos-controladores-angular-8-usando-input)  ).

AHORA lo estoy intentando con  Router parameters además de el manual de ng-book Angular 7,  he seguido las instrucciones de https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-route-parameters-snapshot-parammap-example/ pero sin resultado.
Paso a poner pantallazo que me sale, si veis en la ruta URL si me envia los datos del objeto que estoy enviando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando pulso botón podeis ver la URL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi app-routing tengo definido bien:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ''  , component: MostrarHilosComponent},//principal
  { path: 'login' , component: LoginComponent},// Login
  { path: 'NewFormulario', component: FormularioUsuarioRegistroComponent}, // Inscribirse
  { path: 'Administrar', component: FormAdminComponent }, // administrador Menu   obras
  { path: 'PageEnfermedad', component: PageEnfermedadComponent }, // paginacion
  { path: 'PagePregunta/:enfermedad', component: PagePreguntaComponent }, // paginacion pregunta con enfermedad
  { path: 'PageRespuesta', component: PageRespuestaComponent }, // paginacion
  { path: 'PageReplica', component: PageReplicaComponent }, // paginacion
  { path: 'ErrorBack', component: PageNotFoundComponentComponent}, // Error respuesta back    , no funciona
  { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponentComponent } // 
];
```

En mi enfermedad html tengo .....

```
    <label id="paginacion "> Selecciona una enfermedad y pulsa abajo el botón correspondiente </label>
    <mat-radio-group
    aria-labelledby="paginacion-enfermedades-group-label"
    class="paginacion-radio-group"
    [(ngModel)]="enfermedadSeleccionadaId"
    >
        <mat-radio-button class="paginacion-button" *ngFor="let enfermedad of Enfermedades" 
        [value]="enfermedad" >
            {{enfermedad.enfermedad}}
        </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    ////  quitando Aux no funciona [AuxEnfermedad]="enfermedad" 

<button id="miboton" [routerLink]  ="['/PagePregunta', enfermedadSeleccionadaId ]"      (click) =  buscarPreguntas(enfermedadSeleccionadaId) >Buscar</button>
</div
```

y en mi page-pregunta controller

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PaginacionService } from 'src/app/service/Paginacion.service';
import { CriptoUtilsService } from 'src/app/service/Cripto-utils.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-pregunta',
  templateUrl: './page-pregunta.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-pregunta.component.scss']
})
export class PagePreguntaComponent implements OnInit {

  //@Input() AuxEnfermedad:Enfermedad;
 public enfermedadIn :any;
 public Preguntas=[];
 public page :string;
 public size :string;
 public asc :string;
 public idEnfermedad :string;
 public cadenaTexto :string;

  constructor(private _preguntasServPage :PaginacionService,
              private criptoUtils :CriptoUtilsService,
              private route :ActivatedRoute,
              ) {

               }

  ngOnInit() {
   // this.obtenerPreguntasDeEnfPorIDPaginadas();

   this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{this.enfermedadIn=params['enfermedad']; })
   //this.idEnfermedad=this.AuxEnfermedad.id.toString();
  // console.log (" Dentro paginacion de preguntas  = "+ this.enfermedadIn.id )

  }
```

sin embargo pasa de ello y no se va a esa página sino que va a la que tengo definida como de error de navegación.

No lo entiendo. Necesito pasar datos de un componente a otro y no soy capaz de hacerlo de ningún modo . ¿Qué hago mal?.   Muchas gracias

nota:

He intentado

```
 { path: 'PagePregunta', component: PagePreguntaComponent }, // paginacion pregunta con enfermedad
  { path: 'PagePregunta/:enfermedadSeleccionadaId',redirectTo: 'PagePregunta'  }, // paginacion pregunta con enfermedad
```

y continua dando error, pero ahora si llega a la pagina page-pregunta. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podeis ver, no puedo recoger los valores de `enfermedadSeleccionadaId` me da undefined. Los tengo en la URL pero no los recojo con :

```
 ngOnInit() {
   // this.obtenerPreguntasDeEnfPorIDPaginadas();
debugger
   this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{this.enfermedadIn=params ['enfermedadSeleccionadaId'] ; })
   //this.idEnfermedad=this.AuxEnfermedad.id.toString();
   console.log (" Dentro paginacion de preguntas  = "+ this.enfermedadIn)

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si aun necesitas ayuda, te dejare un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo.
Aunque primero me gustaría mencionar que el paso de parametros por url es una mala practica ya que tienes visibles datos al usuario que pueden o no ser importantes. Sugiero que utilices localStorage o sessionStorage y con un servicio recuperar esos datos.
**1. Definir la ruta (Routing)**

```
{ path: 'pagePregunta:id', component: COMPONENTE}
```

**2. Enviar el dato por RouterLink (HTML)**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/pagePregunta', id]">
```

**3. Capturar el valor en el componente (TypeScript)**

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
){
console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
}
```

Nota:

```
**id** hace referencia al nombre que agregaste al parámetro en las rutas 

**ActivatedRoute** se importa de @angular/router
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Efectivamente. Lo acabe haciendo como dices, con Almacenamiento Local y con Almacenamiento de Sesión. Incluso use cookies. He usado las tres cosas y además, para que no este al alcance de la vista y se pueda manipular, dentro de un servicio puse 'BehaviorSubject' y 'Observables'. Muchas gracias por contestar